# show message on success ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, html

On the success function of jquery ajax request, i have to show a div, can anyone suggest a way to do this

```
dataString = "labid="+val;
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "../pim/manageLabelsAdmin",
cache: false,
data: dataString,
dataType: "json",
success: function(data) {
    if(data.success == "yes"){           
        //alert(data.status);
        } else {
            alert("Occured internal Error. please check network connection");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: The very first suggestion: `$("div").show()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the message to show is in the DOM already, but hidden, you could do something like this in your success callback:

```
if(data.success == "yes")
{            
    $("#id-of-message-element").show();
}
```

Otherwise you could add the message to the DOM using any of `.append()` or `.prepend()` or `.html()` or `.text()` depending on your needs.

More on the DOM insertion methods here:

http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/

Answer (score 0):

if your div has id then this

```
$('#yourDivId').show();
```

else if your fiv has class

```
$('.yourDivClassName').show();
```